# jquery load content - link in the same div where upload content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

after I load content into a div from external html using jquery load function, i want to load another content from another external html,but the button with link to load content is into a loaded div. In first time it was simple, i used this jquery code -

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
 $('li#contact').click(function() {
 $("#section").load("another-page.html #newcontent");
    return false;
});
```

In a new content which I loaded is a div that i want to use as a link.How should the new code? I used this but it didn´t work -

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('anotherpage.html #newcontent #button').click(function() {
    $("#section").load("another-page2.html #newcontent2");
    return false;
});
```

Here is a code from first html page :

```
<ul>
    <li id="contact">Contact</li>
</ul>

<div id="section">
</div>
```

Here is a code from another-page.html (div was loaded into a first html) :

```
<div id="newcontent">

   <div id="button"></div>

</div>
```

And here is a code from another-page2.html :

```
<div id="newcontent2">
</div>
```

Do you have any simple solution on how I right write the second jquery code ?

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('li#contact').click(function() {
    // load first `url`
    $("#section").load("another-page.html #newcontent", function() {
      // when `#button` loaded into `DOM` attach `click` event
      // which loads second `url` at `#button` `click` event
      $("#button").click(function() {
        $("#section").load("another-page2.html #newcontent2");
      })
    }); 
  });
});
```

Comment: Can you add some explanation on how this code solves the asker's problem?